# ssh gives 'Permission Denied' on valid username/password credentials (ssh set to accept password log in)

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, openssh, centos-7

I have a strange issue on a CentOS 7 machine.

If I login from the console, as two different usernames, I'm able to log in.

However, when I try that same username/password combinations, I get `Permission denied`.

Here're the relevant items from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
$ sudo grep -E 'PasswordAuthentication|ChallengeResponseAuthentication|GSSAPIAuthentication|GSSAPICleanupCredentials|UsePAM' /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v '^#'
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes

$ ls -ld ~
drwx------. 17 qa qa 4096 Apr 12 09:37 /home/qa

$ ls -ld ~/.ssh/
drwx------ 2 qa qa 4096 Apr 12 09:37 /home/qa/.ssh/
```

This is a full ssh login try:

```
$ ssh -v qa@install-tests.local 
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to install-tests.local [192.168.1.55] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qa/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qa/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qa/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qa/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qa/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qa/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qa/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/qa/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_2013.58
debug1: no match: dropbear_2013.58
debug1: Authenticating to install-tests.local:22 as 'qa'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 need=20 dh_need=20
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:UkWhDf0R5TVg7Ud3HRmp+azue0T0jc5GzTQwLoCTQQQ
debug1: Host 'install-tests.local' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/qa/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/qa/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/qa/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/qa/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/qa/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
qa@install-tests.local's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
qa@install-tests.local's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
qa@install-tests.local's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about an ls -l ~/.ssh  to see the permissions on the files inside the .ssh directory? That would be helpful. Nice job on posting the info you did, though.

Comment: Since the problem isn't related to ssh keys, I'm not sure the files inside ~/.ssh are of interest. In any case, there is only the `known_host` file with _644_ permission. @superboot

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was not related to ssh, but to a mixup in DNS, which pointed the FQDN of the machine to the wrong IP address.
Obviously, once that was fixed, there're no more issues with ssh.